# Backbone handling json array vs json object

Tags: json, backbone.js

How should I handle json returned as array in Backbone.Collection's overridden parse?

I used the following for json returned as object:

```
parse: function(response) {
  return response.results;
}
```

What about when json gets returned as array?

Answer (score 0):

Backbone, by default, expects an array. If the array is nested within an object, you need to over-ride `parse()` as you have done above. However, if the response returns an array, you don't need to do anything (since that is what backbone is expecting). Finally, if you are expecting a mix of the two (that is, might be an array sometimes and might be an object the other times, see dbaseman's answer).